# Multiobjective integer programming

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, gurobi, integer-programming

I wish to use integer programming to enumerate pareto optimal solutions.
I would like to implement an algorithm that uses gurobi or a similar single-objective integer programming solver to do this, but I don't know any such algorithms. Could someone please propose an algorithm for enumerating the efficient frontier?

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I'll address how to enumerate all pareto efficient solutions of 2-objective pure integer optimization problems of the form

```
min_x {g'x, h'x}
s.t.  Ax <= b
      x integer
```

#### Algorithm

We start the algorithm by optimizing for one of the objectives (we'll use `g` here). Since this is a standard single-objective integer optimization problem, it can be easily solved with gurobi or any other LP solver:

```
min_x g'x
s.t.  Ax <= b
      x integer
```

We initialize a set `P`, which will eventually contain all the pareto efficient solutions, to `P = {x*}`, where `x*` is the optimal solution of this model. To get the next point on the efficient frontier, which has the second-smallest `g'x` value and an improved `h'x` value, we can add the following constraints to our model:

1. Remove `x*` from the feasible set of solutions (details on these `x != x*` constraints are provided later in the answer).
2. Add a constraint that `h'x <= h'x*`

The new optimization model that we need to solve is:

```
min_x g'x
s.t.  Ax <= b
      x != x* for all x* in P
      h'x <= h'x* for all x* in P
      x integer
```

Again, this is a single-objective integer optimization model that can be solved with gurobi or another solver (once you follow the details below on how to model `x != x*` constraints). As you repeatedly solve this model, adding the optimal solutions to `P`, solutions will get progressively larger (worse) `g'x` values and progressively smaller (better) `h'x` values. Eventually, the model will become infeasible, which means no more points on the pareto frontier exist, and the algorithm terminates.

At this point, there may be some pairs of solutions `x, y` in `P` for which `g'x = g'y` and `h'x > h'y`, in which case `x` is dominated by `y` and can be removed. After filtering in this way, the set `P` represents the full pareto efficient frontier.

#### `x != x*` Constraints

All that remains is to model constraints of the form `x != x*`, where `x` and `x*` are n-dimensional vectors of integer variables. Even in one dimension this is a non-convex constraint (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37078/127715) for details), so we need to add auxiliary variables to help us model the constraint.

Denote the `n` variables stored in the optimization model (collectively denoted `x`) as `x_1, x_2, ..., x_n`, and similarly denote the variable values in `x*` as `x*_1, x*_2, ..., x*_n`. We can add new binary variables `y_1, y_2, ..., y_n` to the model, where `y_i` is set to 1 when `x_i > x*_i`. Because `x_i` and `x*_i` are integer valued, this is the same as saying `x_i >= x*_i + 1`, and this can be implemented with the following constraints (`M` is a large constant):

```
x_i - x*_i >= 1 - M(1-y_i) for all i = 1, ..., n
```

Similarly, we can add new binary variables `z_1, z_2, ..., z_n` to the model, where `z_i` is set to 1 when `x_i < x*_i`. Because `x_i` and `x*_i` are integer valued, this is the same as saying `x_i <= x*_i - 1`, and this can be implemented with the following big-`M` constraints:

```
x_i - x*_i <= -1 + M(1-z_i) for all i = 1, ..., n
```

If at least one of the `y` or `z` variables is set, then we know that our `x != x*` constraint is satisfied. Therefore, we can replace `x != x*` with:

```
y_1 + y_2 + ... + y_n + z_1 + z_2 + ... + z_n >= 1
```

In short, each `x != x*` constraint can be handled by adding `2n` binary variables and `2n+1` constraints to the model, where `n` is the number of variables in the original model.

Comment: Thanks, sampling method is very nice, but it could be imprecise. Is there a way that I could generate all optimal-frontier, without missing anyone of them?

Comment: Consider I am dealing with integer programming

Comment: @william007 I've updated with an algorithm that is guaranteed to enumerate the entire efficient frontier for a 2-objective integer program.

Answer (score 1):

[PolySCIP](http://scip.zib.de/#polyscip) is an academic open-source solver for multi-objective mixed integer linear programs. In case you do not want to implement your own solver or want to compare yours with another one.